# Transfer from Sanke Keg to Corny keg?

Tags: kegs, sanke-keg

I would like to put craft beers on my tap system at home. Is it possible and safe to depressurize a full sanke keg and pour that beer into a corny keg so I can connect and enjoy at home?

Other suggestions?

Comment: You should really look into getting this, I have it and it is awesome. [Conversion Kit](http://www.cornykeg.com/resources/corny-keg-tips/converting-sanke-ball-lock-keg/)

Answer (score 3):

Why not build a hose that goes from the Sanke fitting to the liquid side of your Corny?  I'd use CO2 at the lowest pressure that you can to get the liquid to move.  Otherwise, use a growler filler with a tube that is long enough to reach the bottom of your corny keg and treat the corny as a growler.  When you get home, connect as usual.

Comment: I dont have a Sanke fitting and was trying to do this using my corny kegs.  Most craft breweries will not fill a personal corny and only let you buy the beer and put a deposit on the keg, a stanke keg.

Comment: @RyanWhitt either way you will need a sanke fitting, why not just add a sanke line to your homebrew system?

Comment: Gotcha.  That's what i figured, but was trying to get around it.  Didnt want to mess around switching out the sanke when I use the spot for corny, vice versa.

Comment: You can get quick disconnect for a sanke fitting that have the same thread as the male end of your corny gas and liquid fittings. So swapping fittings can be done in a minute or two. I have a 3-tap tower and can serve any combination of homebrew or commercial.